# AspectJ like annotations in C++?

Tags: java, c++, spring, annotations

In Spring Aspect Oriented programming, we can define/use annotations to specify preprocessing or postprocessing or both operations for method being executed.

For example:
If I want every it func1() executes, it should be logged. I can do it by defining annotation say @LogThisFunction. And annotating func1 with it like below:

@LogThisFunction(params if requried )
void func1() { ... }

And now I can keep using this annotation for other functions.

So my question is, can we write such annotation in C++?

Comment: You can but it requires preprocessing or custom compiler. As I recall Parcplace had an aspects implementation for C++. But this was at least a decade ago.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for quick input... Yes, I guess you are talking about AspectC++ (http://www.aspectc.org/Documentation.php). I think, this is what I was looking for, but as you said it requires custom compiler (http://www.aspectc.org/Download.php). Let me go through it. Thanks so much for pointing me in direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers my question: http://www.aspectc.org/Documentation.php

Thanks @Cheersandhth